# Pull Information From Multiple Worksheets And Consolidate and Sum By Vendor

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out the best way to return information from multiple worksheets into a consolidated summed total worksheet but having a problem getting to completion.

I am trying to take information from 2 different reports (1) Master Vendor/Factory List) and (2) Capacity By Factory sans Vendor Name as how its currently provided by the vendor.

[image: Capacity Worksheet]
[image: Vendor List]

I want to be able to, in a separate worksheet return the results plus the capacity values into a consolidated worksheet.  Ideally, after each vendor I would also like to Sum the totals.  Total vendor list well over 100.

[image: Ideal Final State]

I have tried multiple Index functions but feel like there is a scan needed that I am not able to figure out how to complete or that the code is more complex than I am capable of figuring out on my own.

Thanks for any help those that can provide.  Open to taking small portions to try and solve.

Comment: *I am trying to figure out* and *I want to be able to* - see next comment.

Comment: Please do not come here with a list of requirements and an expectation that someone is going to write all of your code for free. This is counter to the site's conditions and requirements that you agreed upon when joining this community and frankly, more than just a little insulting to the altruistic volunteers whose valuable time and attention you've misdirected in your request to have someone do your work for you. Take a step back and read all of the readily available Help white papers on what sort of question (and effort on your part) is expected before posting your question.

Comment: No offense but I have been spending my time trying to figure out different approaches and they aren't coming together.  You want me to splil out all of the various formulas and failed attempts in order to try and at least point in the right direction.  Not trying to be insulting. I am trying to figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: This might seem counter-productive to you but in this community we correct original effort; we go not supply key-turn code without some original effort.

Comment: I am not looking for someone to write it out for me and plug-n-play.  Jeeped go relax with a beer and forget I even asked for guidance.  Repeat, guidance..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power Query / Get and Transform to combine multiple sheets into one data source and then use pivot tables to report on that combined data. You may need to revisit the data architecture of the original sources to ensure that the data can be combined with logic that does not require human intervention.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will check that out.  I have started already seeing what I can do to adjust the original sources.  Thought that was a good area to start on first.  Appreciate the suggestion